# With maven, add a dependency to pom and download it?

Tags: java, maven

This is a really simple question, but I searched for a resolution and nothing is working for me. I added the below to my pom.xml, but can't import `org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser` in my `class`. When I run mvn install, I get the below output.

```
<dependencies> 
      ....

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    ....
 </dependencies>
```

```
D:\java\my_project>mvn install    
[INFO] Scanning for projects...    
[INFO] Building my_project 1.0-SNAPSHOT

[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.commons:commons-csv:jar:1.1.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available

[INFO] BUILD FAILURE    

[INFO] Total time: 0.644 s    
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-07-21T08:46:47-04:00    
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/245M    

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project my_project: Could not resolve depen dencies for project com.myproject:artifact:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.apache.commons:commons-csv:jar:1.1.1-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]  
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.    
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.   
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:    
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException nException
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why are you using the snapshot? The snapshot version is a alpha/beta version, which might be unstable. It's also not uploaded to the standard Maven repo, so you would need to do some extra work to use it. If you use 1.1 it should work.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: oh, I had copied that from apache's site. Works now, thanks. Will mark as correct when enough time has passed.